# ASP.net MVC 5 C# returning the double from within IF statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, double

how do i access the double from within the IF statement

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Iflexcst([Optional] float Quan, [Optional] float kammid, [Optional] float kammod, [Optional] float SpacerInnerDim, [Optional] float SpacerOuterDim, [Optional] float WashOuterDim, [Optional]float IsoWashInnerDim, [Optional]float SteelWashInnerDim, [Optional] float SteelWashQuan, [Optional] float IsoWashQuan, FormCollection form)
    {
        //other functions removed
        if (WashOuterDim <= 43.6)
        {

            double washerSerrTime = 0.6;
            double SerrWasherRun = (washerSerrTime * IsoWashQuan) * (1 / 60);
            ViewBag.SerrWasherRun = SerrWasherRun;

            double SerrWasherRunPrice = ((SerrateSetup / Quan) + washerSerrTime) * serrateRate;
            ViewBag.SerrWasherRunPrice = SerrWasherRunPrice;

        }

        if (WashOuterDim > 43.6)
        {


            double washerSerrTime = 0.833;
            double SerrWasherRun = (washerSerrTime * IsoWashQuan) * (1 / 60);
            ViewBag.SerrWasherRun = SerrWasherRun;

            double SerrWasherRunPrice = ((SerrateSetup / Quan) + washerSerrTime) * serrateRate;
            ViewBag.SerrWasherRunPrice = SerrWasherRunPrice;


        }


        // Adds together all costs 
        float Price = (float)SerrWasherRunPrice;
```

It recommends creating a getting and setting for "SerrWasherRunPrice" or making it a public variable, but both these solutions give me conflicts with another declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you store it on `ViewBag` all the times you can take it from there, in this way you don't have to change your code to much.

```
// Adds together all costs 
float Price = (float)ViewBag.SerrWasherRunPrice;
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the declaration of variable outside of the `if`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Iflexcst([Optional] float Quan, [Optional] float kammid, [Optional] float kammod, [Optional] float SpacerInnerDim, [Optional] float SpacerOuterDim, [Optional] float WashOuterDim, [Optional]float IsoWashInnerDim, [Optional]float SteelWashInnerDim, [Optional] float SteelWashQuan, [Optional] float IsoWashQuan, FormCollection form)
{
    //other functions removed
    double SerrWasherPrice = 0;
    if (WashOuterDim <= 43.6)
    {

        double washerSerrTime = 0.6;
        double SerrWasherRun = (washerSerrTime * IsoWashQuan) * (1 / 60);
        ViewBag.SerrWasherRun = SerrWasherRun;

        SerrWasherRunPrice = ((SerrateSetup / Quan) + washerSerrTime) * serrateRate;
        ViewBag.SerrWasherRunPrice = SerrWasherRunPrice;

    }
   else
    {
        double washerSerrTime = 0.833;
        double SerrWasherRun = (washerSerrTime * IsoWashQuan) * (1 / 60);
        ViewBag.SerrWasherRun = SerrWasherRun;

        SerrWasherRunPrice = ((SerrateSetup / Quan) + washerSerrTime) * serrateRate;
        ViewBag.SerrWasherRunPrice = SerrWasherRunPrice;


    }


    // Adds together all costs 
    float Price = (float)SerrWasherRunPrice;
```

Number after the declaration is not important, as it will be changed in the `if` clause. Also, the second `if` should be changed to `else`

Comment: I tried doing exactly this, and it gave me Error 1 A local variable named 'SerrWasherRunPrice' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'SerrWasherRunPrice', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else